# converting text to number in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have the following problem in excel,
i have a column with the following type of values

```
1.0
2.0
1.0
3.0
4.0
```

Excel is treating it as text and when i try to follow any steps practically nothing happens

I selected the values and change their type in properties and nothing happened. Then I went to official excel site and followed their steps and still nothing happened

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885

I have excel 2010, i tried a few of the solutions but they didnt really give me what I want! If you have a link or solution please provide. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this formula in another column:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;".";","))
```

"B2" standing for the range, where your data is.

Depends what your decimal seperator in your language is. If it's english the function VALUE should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub numerify()
    Dim rng As Range, v As Double, r As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            v = CDbl(Trim(r.Text))
            r.Clear
            r.Value = v
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Here a list of links that might help you with a solution:

[Excel Formula: Convert Number to Text](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-text-to-numbers)

[Excel Easy Text to Numbers](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-numbers.html)